# How to make a selection in one tap from a list in symbian

Tags: symbian

I created a **CAknEnumeratedTextPopupSettingItem** control using Carbide.C++ 2.7 as it looks below:

(**known as enumeratedTextPopup control in Carbide.C++ IDE** )

[image]

And I'm using Symbian S60 5th Ed SDK; And Targeting Symbian S60 5th Ed, Symbian^3, Symbian Anna.

**Now I want to know how to make this control follow one tap style ( One tap to highlight and select ). Is there any flags needed or properties to set ?**

The way the control works is, one tap to highlight, and another tap to select.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symbian S60 5th Ed doesn't support one tap to activate and select an item; This feature is supported
by Symbian^3 and forward.

**Symbian^3 Application Developer Library**

```
 S60 5th Edition introduced touch support feature with double-tap to maintain binary 
 and source code compatibility with the existing S60 3.x applications.



Symbian^3 enhances the touch support with single tap for achieving better usability
and development of platform and 3rd party applications. The supporting UI is based on 
direct manipulation and is not focus driven, which means that a single-tap on the 
device selects and activates an event.
```

So, if the application created by S60 5th Ed and targeting both Symbian S60 5th Ed and Symbian^3,
Then "**Slider**" control could be used in place of "**enumeratedTextPopup**".

[Find more details about migrating application from Symbian S60 5th Ed to Symbian^3.](http://bit.ly/n80MWZ)